# Extending Image Model for Videos

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I currently have a machine learning model trained on 100k images and is able to identify spoof images with very high accuracy.  Is there a way an image model could be extended to detect spoof frames in videos?

I was looking for modifications in training framework that I need to do to extend this model to video anomaly detection.

To clarify: For test case, the test videos could be split into individual frames which can be run through my image model. The image model should be able to accurately identify the spoof frames and thereby identify spoof faces in videos. I am confused on how the training needs to be modified. Any inputs will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check [YOLO](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/wiki/YOLO:-Real-Time-Object-Detection) or [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) for localization of detected area. These models are localize detected area and returns bounding boxes that contains width, height, x and y coordinate of detected box.